# From which film did they use this younger Alec Baldwin in 30 Rock?

Tags: identify-this-movie, 30-rock

In [Season 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/30_Rock_%28season_4%29) Episode 7 of *[30 Rock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/30_Rock)*, various cast members walk in front of a HD camera which then shows alternate versions of each person.

For [Alec Baldwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alec_Baldwin) it shows him much younger, and this looks like it was taken from an early film. Which film was it lifted from?

[image]

Here is a YouTube clip. The scene is at 1 min 12 secs in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IMDb's [movie connections page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1528320/movieconnections) for the episode states:

> **Features:**
>   [*The Hunt for Red October (1990)*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099810/combined)
>   A shot of young Alec Baldwin is shown on the HD Camera monitor

Here's a frame from the movie with Baldwin in a similar suit:

[image]

Comment: It's definitely from the scene in "The Hunt for Red October" when the jet crashes into the flight deck on the aircraft carrier.